Feedback network for EGS002 pure sine wave module
I'm lately working on a pure sine wave inverter. Vin=12-24 V, bus voltage is set at 200 V DC.
I have tested the full bridge at 370 V DC max everything works great it's just the feedback part where I want to keep the output limited to 110 V AC.
Hence how can a modify the feedback voltage divider value? This might be elementary but the circuit literally sense the sinusoidal waveform from the LC output filter hence I can't really understand the fundamental.
https://www.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/1132081/EGMICRO/EGS002/341/1/EGS002.html

The circuit that I've used is the same as in datasheet.
Also the boost stage can provide max power of 70 W at maintaining 250 V DC before dropping. I just want to power simple 20 W load. Whenever the circuit has no load the standby current is only 0.05 mA.
For further information I will reply asap. Your help is very important thanks in advance

No need to yell!

Changed your title so you are no longer SHOUTING AT US.  Also corrected some typos...

What happens if you reduce the value of R19?

@Reducing the value does not change much because the threshold is still way above then the needed 200v level,ive tested by replacing R9 with 100k
